How can you efficiently perform a “tolerant” search in large files with PHP?
I have an online dictionary with more than 200.000 entries as a file that runs well under PHP on a server. I would like to extend this with the option of a “tolerant” search with PHP (similar to agrep under Unix). This means that I not only want to find exact matches, but (in case the search query fails) I also want similar entries to be displayed as a result for a search query that contains, for example, a wrong letter or has one letter too many or too few in any position. How can this be realized with PHP efficient without increasing the computing effort too much? The uncompressed source file is several megabytes in size.
I tried to work with regular expressions, but the effort quickly became too great.
About the data structure:
Each entry is separated by a line feed from the next entry.
Each entry consists of two parts (a German part and an English part) which are separated by two consecutive colons.
Each of the two parts can have any number of sub-parts, which are separated by a vertical line.
About the search:
It is possible to search bidirectional (German and English at the same time) or unidirectional (either German to English or English to German).
You can search for whole words or sentences, but also for parts of words.
Upper and lower case can be considered or ignored during the search.

similar to agrep under Unix - technically you can call grep on php using shell_exec. though beware of the security implications. if my corpus is large, i'd go with something of a proper index like [tag:elasticsearch] or [tag:solr].

You can avoid the cost of the similarity search in most circumstances by doing the exact-only match first, and then falling back to the similarity search if nothing is found. Even then though, what sort of performance are you looking for? It takes my low-power work machine just 0.03s to run levenshtein() on 100K words. So, I guess, how often does the exact search fail?

And what is the data structure of your data?

@Bagus Tesa: "grep" is not suitable, only "agrep" would be.

@Alex Howansky: You are right with the exact search first and similarity search only on fails. That is exactly what I want to do.
But how would you use levenshtein() to get the proper results? It is also possible to get thousands of possible results on one search.

The problem seems to be that the data structure is too complex to use the levenshtein() function, as the entries are not unique and the search string may occur multiple times as part of the whole string of each entry that I want to compare with the search query. What I need is something like a function preg_match_levenshtein().
I have an idea to solve this problem by creating two more files (one English and one German) containing only unique entries of all possible words of both languages. If the search fails, I split the search string into individual words and search the two files iteratively for matches or for the distance of the deviation using the levenshtein() function. Words that match in at least one of the two files are eliminated from the search string as they are written correctly and may not responsible for the search failing. The remaining words are collected in an array to be further processed with levenshtein() and finally to display suggestions, provided the Levenshtein distance is not too large and the number of letters does not fall below a minimum.
This method can only be used for spelling errors, but not for correctly spelled words that have only been swapped in the search string.
